# bias is large relative to the variance when we pool information over small samples or when data is highly stratified?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, bias, pooling

I am reading Yudi Pawitan's In All Likelihood Chapter 5. The book makes the following assertion on MLE bias.

"...bias is large relative to the variance when we pool information over small samples or when data is highly stratified..."

I do not see the proof of the statement.

What is the proof of the statement? I could consider small samples with little variation and it seems that in that case, the MLE variance estimator has asymptotic bias smaller than the standard deviation of MLE variance estimator.

Comment: It is discussed at the beginning of the chapter - 5.1, which then refers to 10.1.  [But the argument is not about asymptotics?]

Comment: @seanv507 So it is proved in 10.1? If so, I will look at it later during the day.

Comment: Illustrated with two examples might be a better description.  The first is two samples each from a large number $N$ of normal distributions $\mathcal N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$ - i.e. $2N$ observations and $N+1$ unknown parameters.  The difficulty comes when you try to use maximum likelihood to estimate $\sigma^2$.